# Spring REST API - Handle UnrecognizedPropertyException to return meaningful error to client

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I have a standard spring API and I'm trying to add custom code to handle the case when a client adds an undefined field (in other words, not defined by the object annotated with @RequestBody). Currently, when a client does add an undefined field to the request, the API returns a `400` status, with no error message. Based on my understanding, this is happening because Jackson is throwing the `UnrecognizedPropertyException` before any of my code is even executing. I would like to be able to return a message to the client stating which field(s) need to be removed by handling this exception manually. Sample code:

```
   public class RequestInput {
       Integer id;
   }
```

```
    @PutMapping
    public Object updateObject(@RequestBody RequestInput requestInput) throws Exception {
        // Execution does not even reach this point when the client adds an undefined field to requestInput.
        // For instance: PUT localhost:8080/objectAPI/ { "id":5, "undefinedField": "hi" }
    }
```

Is there an annotation I could use here that I'm not aware of? Or is there some other manual way to handle this? I'm not interested in simply doing something like `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` because I want my API to be strict.

Comment: Use `@RestControllerAdvice` to handle exceptions. You can compose the custom response.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a function that able to handle those exception before spring framework does it for you.

You can use this annotation @ExceptionHandler in every of your controller class capture specific Exception that you wanted then manage there to create a meaningful error to your clients, or you can define such behavior for all your REST API endpoints by creating a new class annotate with @ControllerAdvice.

There is more length to this answer in which I provide an excellent references where the author explained more in-depth detail.

Link Reference:
[Guide to Spring Boot REST API Error Handling](https://www.toptal.com/java/spring-boot-rest-api-error-handling#:%7E:text=ExceptionHandler%20is%20a%20Spring%20annotation,thrown%20within%20this%20controller%20only.)
[Error Handling for REST with Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring)